# Regular Expression to Split String based on word

Tags: java, regex

I have an expression like

> 'Variable1' > 0 and 'Variable2 <0  or 'Variable3 >50

I want to split this string based on logical operators like *"and"* and *"or"* using regular expression.

Expected output:

> 'Variable1' > 0
>   and
>   'Variable2 <0
>   or
>   'Variable3 >50

More Complicate expression using parenthesis:

> ((a1 >40 or a5 <50) and a2 >30) or a4 >50

If any body help me regular expression to split these expression with connector like 'and' and 'or'.

Comment: @AbdulFatir Stop formatting non-code blocks as code. Thank you. (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should match and not split,specially when you have a complicated expression:

```
String pattern="\w+\s*[<>]\s*\d+|and|or";
Matcher m= Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);
while(m.find()) 
{
    System.out.println(m);
}
```